# Writing a program that examines if a number is armstrong and magical or neither using functions

Tags: c

I am a beginner in C language. I wanted to write a program to figure out whether a number is an armstrong and if it is a magical number or neither. I wrote a function for this purpose that'll return 1 if the number is an armstrong number and 0 if otherwise.

This is the image of the error:

[image]

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int is_armstrong(int n)
{
    int temp = n, sum1 = 0, d;
    while (temp > 0)
    {
        d=temp % 10;
        sum1= sum1 + (d * d * d);
        temp = temp / 10;
    }
    if (n == sum1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int is_magical(int n)
{
    int temp = n, d, sum1 = 0, r;
    while (temp > 0)
    {
        d = temp % 10;
        sum1 = sum1 + d;
        temp = temp / 10;
    }
    temp = sum1;
    while (temp > 0)
    {
        d = temp % 10;
        r = r * 10 + d;
        temp = temp / 10;
    }
    if (sum1 * r == n)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n, i, l;
    i = is_armstrong(n);
    l = is_magical(n);
    printf("enter the number");
    scanf("%d",n);

    if (i == 1)
    {
        printf("the number is armstrong\n");
    }
    else if (i == 0)
    {
        printf("the number is armstrong\n");
    }

    if (l == 1)
    {
        printf("the number is magical\n");
    }
    else if (l == 0)
    {
        printf("the number is magical\n");
    }
    else 
      printf("neither");
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d",n);` --> `scanf("%d",&n);`

Comment: `i=is_armstrong(n);` This gets called before `n` is initialized.

Comment: `print` statement under the `IF` condition is also incorrect. That should be different. check the print statement and fix the above-listed errors. Both `i=is_armstrong(n);`
   and `l=is_magical(n);` is called before the initialization of `n` variable.

Comment: please do not post links to images, rather copy/paste the text into your question

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. corrects the logic errors
4. corrects the output text errors
5. removes unneeded comparisons
6. contains appropriate vertical spacing, for readability

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int is_armstrong(int n)
{
   int temp=n,sum1=0,d;
   
   while(temp>0)
   {
       d=temp%10;
       sum1= sum1 + (d*d*d);
       temp = temp/10;
   }
   
   if (n== sum1)
   {
       return 1;
   }
   
   else
   {
       return 0;
   }
}


int is_magical(int n)
{
   int temp =n, d, sum1 = 0, r;
   
   while (temp>0)
   {
       d=temp%10;
       sum1= sum1 + d;
       temp = temp /10;
   }
   
   temp =sum1;
   while (temp>0)
   {
       d = temp%10;
       r=r*10 +d;
       temp =temp/10;
   }
   
   if ( (sum1 * r) == n)
   {
       return 1;
   }
   
   else
   {
       return 0;
   }
}


int main( void )
{
   int n,i,l;
   
   printf("enter the number");
   scanf("%d",&n);

   i=is_armstrong(n);
   l=is_magical(n);
   
   if (i==1)
   {
       printf("the number is armstrong\n");
   }
   
   else 
   {
       printf("the number is not armstrong\n");
   }
   
   if (l==1)
   {
       printf("the number is magical\n");
   }
   
   else
   {
       printf("the number is not magical\n");
   }
   
   if( i==0 && l==0 )
   { 
       printf("neither");
   }
}
```